# What's the noun in English that describes the power that a certain book has in attracting its readers?

Tags: word-request

What's the noun in English that describes the power that a certain book has in attracting its readers?

I am especially interested in such a noun that would go along well with the verb "lose". For example:

> With the first volume, you could say that I just swallowed it within
>   one night - so much riveting it was. Then it took us all a long two
>   years to wait for the second volume to come out. I bought it just
>   yesterday. I didn't have time to read it through. I only read the first 5
>   pages, but that was enough to tell that the book **hasn't lost its
>   _____________** at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One word possibilities:

- **Appeal** (the most appropriate in the context)
- Attraction
- Charm
- Pull
- Allure

We also have a British English term *[pulling-power](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pulling%20power)* to refer to someone or something's ability to draw an audience.